# Why is the .click() function not working?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, click

When I try to run the code it first runs perfectly fine but at the end, the link doesn't get clicked!
I also tried the `.submit()` function but it also didn't work.
This is the line that pops up:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mount_0_0_3z"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/button[1]').click()
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click'
```

Code:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from data import username, password


def login(username, password):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get('https://instagram.com')
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mount_0_0_3z"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/button[1]').click()
    time.sleep(2)
login(username, password)
```

Comment: Is the xpath correct ?

Comment: Yes it is the right xpath!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `WebDriverWait`? The element may be visible in the DOM but it may also need to be VISIBLE. What does visible mean? It means the button not only needs to be in the DOM but it needs to have a height and width greater than 0. Here is a snippet you can try:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


def wait_for_element_clickable(driver, x_path, timeout):
    """Waits for an element to be visible and clickable, then clicks the element.
    Visible means that the element is not only in the DOM but has
    a width and height greater than 0.

    Args:
        x_path (str): The XPATH for the element.
        timeout (int): The amount of time to wait for the element to be visible and clickable.
        click (bool, optional): Click the element after it is available. Defaults to False.
    """
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, x_path))
        )

        element.click()
        print("Element has been clicked")
        return True
    except TimeoutException as te:
        print(f"Element was not found: {te}")
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

As @ekoret already mentioned, it might be that the element hasn't had enough time to load.

When using Selenium, it is a good idea to always use the WebDriverWait funcionality. Here is a code snippet you could implement on all your scripts quite easily:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome() #This assumes the chromedriver is on the same folder as your script

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Now you can use the WebDriverWait everytime you search for an element
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, your_xpath_here)))
element.click()
```

Depending on the element's nature, you might want to use other methods instead of element_to_be_clickable. Some examples include presence_of_element_located, element_to_be_visible.

You can check the [documentation][1] for more info.

Hope it helped!
[1]: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html